# jacoco.exec not getting generated after tomcat restart

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, jacoco

I have added below lines to `setenv.bat` under `%tomcat%/bin` directory.

```
SET JACOCO="-javaagent:C:\jacoco-agent-jar\jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=localhost,port=6300,destfile=C:\jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=*"

SET JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% %JACOCO%
```

And then restarted the tomcat server couple of times by changing output values etc, but no luck. I also checked after restart, whether `Java_opts` environment variable got set or not. But it got listed.

Thanks in advance. Please suggest on if anything I am missing here.

Comment: Let's clear up your question!

Comment: Adding JAVA_OPTS/MAVEN_OPTS to tomcat JVM arguments, once I restart the tomcat server, jacoco.exec is not getting generated/visible at "destFile" location.

Comment: Adding JAVA_OPTS/MAVEN_OPTS to tomcat JVM arguments, once I restart the tomcat server, jacoco.exec is not getting generated/visible at "destFile" location.Step-by-step description for implementing Jacoco on-the-fly instrumentation on remote JVM would be great help (since I have already implemented Jacoco off-line instrumentation inside pom.xml)

Comment: @DoNhuVy:- Mailed the details

Comment: If you run Tomcat and if in the Tomcat start script / command (which actually starts the JVM to host your .war/application etc) has those OPTS getting successfully passed to it, then it must should create the jacoco.exec file. For ex: I start Tomcat and then I see a 0 byte .exec file (destfile value). Then I run non-unit tests, at this point the file size is still not populated. I stop the Tomcat, now it populates the .exec file.  export PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS=-javaagent:your/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=somefolder/jacocoIT.exec,append=false

Comment: Thanks arun for reply..In tomcat install deirectory, I dont see any bat file like (catalina.bat, startup.bat etc). I can only see it as a windows service. Just for checking purpose, I downloaded other zip distribution where I can see list of .bat files under %CATALINA%\bin dir. So what could be the best way here to test/check whether JVM initializing all the args including my jacoco-java-agent? By the way, I also tried adding these args under Java tab of Tomcat-config windows, but no luck.